# so, I am working on this project which includes lots of subfolders with html ,css and js files, How do i start browser sync?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, browser-sync

My `index.html` is located at `\Desktop\conFusion\app.index`,
and inside `conFusion` folder I have this bower component folder which include the needed css and js files.
I wrote:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "**/*.*"
```

[image: This is the screenshot of browser and cmd]

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Where is your code?

Comment: First of all, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Secondly, show code and errors as text, not as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see what your directory structure is I am going to show you what mine is, in hopes that will help.  This is not a Fusion app but I would guess it would have to be similar.  In my root web project I have:

index.html
scripts (folder)
stylesheets (folder)

Its in this root directory that I run the browser-sync command:

browser-sync start --server --files "stylesheets/*.css, scripts/*.js, *.html"

I am hoping this helps.

Comment: Can you post your directory structure of the project?